# Is there an easy way to re-run failed external data sets?

Tags: azure-data-factory

I've got roughly 60 files that didn't turn up when they should have done and therefore data factory has missed their arrival and marked them as failed validation.

To rerun, the only method I know of is to either click each individually and then "re-run" in the azure portal or use powershell.

Is there any way to bulk rerun in the azure portal or is there any way to re-run external sources in the monitor and manage application?

Answer (score 0):

In the portal, click "Monitor & Manage", this will open in a new tab.

Filter the activity list to show the ones you are interested in (filter pipeline, status etc); then select multiple rows with shift+click or ctrl+click. THen click the "Rerun" option in that window....all rows selected will be rerun

Comment: I don't think that will show external datasets though, only the dependant activities. The monitor and manage portal shows these slices as waiting for dataset, it's only the Azure Portal that shows the data slices as failed validation.

Comment: Hitting rerun in monitor and manage will return that slice to waiting - dataset dependences. It doesn't recognise the file as having arrived.

Comment: Yes of course, my apologies. I would write a PowerShell script in that case.